# How is $\int dy = ln(y)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $\frac{d^2 y}{d x^2}=\left(\frac{d y}{d x}\right)^2$

Sol. $\frac{d^2 y}{d x^2}=\left(\frac{d y}{d x}\right)^2$

or $\quad \frac{d}{d x}\left(\frac{d y}{d x}\right)=\left(\frac{d y}{d x}\right)^2$

or $\quad d\left(\frac{d y}{d x}\right)=\left(\frac{d y}{d x}\right)^2 d x$

or $\\ \frac{d\left(\frac{d y}{d x}\right)}{\left(\frac{d y}{d x}\right)}=\left(\frac{d y}{d x}\right) d x$

or $\quad \int \frac{d\left(\frac{d y}{d x}\right)}{\frac{d y}{d x}}=\int dy$.

$\therefore \log \left(\frac{d y}{d x}\right)=\underbrace{\log y+\log C_1}--->How?$

$\therefore \frac{d y}{d x}=C_1 y$

$\therefore \ y=C_2e^{C_1x}$

This is the solution given in the book and I can't understand how integral of 1 is ln(y) ?? please help...

Comment: Have you tried to replace their "solution" in the original equation and see if it is indeed a solution? If it is not, then obviously they've made some mistake. E.g. does $y=e^x$ (which corresponds to $C_1=C_2=1$) satisfy $y''=(y')^2$?

Comment: Seems like a print error

Comment: If by "the book" you mean "the solutions manual for the exercises" then you should be aware that far fewer eyes check those for accuracy.

Comment: Ok must be printing mistake but it is very reputated book so I thought I was missing something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is obviously incorrect, you could take the (dy/dx)^2 term in the denominator and integrate twice to obtain $$y= -ln(x+C_1) + C_2$$ as the solution

Answer (score 1):

Another way you could solve this is by substitution;

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=t$$

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{dt}{dx}$$

Then we get,

$$\frac{dt}{dx}=t^2$$

$$\int \frac{1}{t^2}\,dt=\int\,dx$$

$$t=\frac{-1}{c_1+x}$$

Put back $t$,

$$\int\,dy=\int \frac{-1}{c_1+x} \,dx$$

$$\boxed{y=-ln(c_1+x)+c_2}$$

Comment: $$+1$$ $$Thanks$$

Comment: @XZYY A Hint: There is a little rule - [See Mathematics Stack Exchange > Help center > Privileges](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):

"When shouldn't I comment?
[...] Compliments which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!"); instead, upvote it and pay it forward;"

Comment: $$@KevinDietrich$$ $$+1$$ $$Great\ Hint!$$ $$Will\ keep\ in\ mind\ from\ now\ !$$